# Create a blank space the same size as text, equations etc

Tags: spacing, align

I would like to create a space in my document the same size (height and width) of a certain set of text. (For context, it will compile the TEXT when I want solutions and SPACE when I only want the questions).

I have a solution to this, except when I have an `align` environment. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Here I want the text and equation:}

\lipsum[4] 
\begin{align*}
x + y = 3
\end{align*}

\textbf{Here I want blank space the same size as the equation:}

\phantom{%
\lipsum[4] 
\begin{align*}
x + y = 3
\end{align*}%
}

\end{document}
```

gives the error "Missing \endgroup inserted". I'm aware there's a problem with `\phantom` (and `\vspace` etc) and `\align`. So I'm hoping there's a workaround. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it will end up in hardcopy, you could do a `\color{white}` and `\color{black}` to switch back and forth.

Comment: Thanks, but it will be an electronic version. So text will still be able to be highlighted (copy/paste etc) if I simply change the colour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use`\phantom{\vbox{....}}`. This will put the text and `align` environment into a vertical box which can be fed to `\phantom` then. See the two pages in `continous` mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\textbf{Here I want the text and equation:}
\lipsum[4] 
\begin{align*}
x + y = 3
\end{align*}

\textbf{Here I want blank space the same size as the equation:}
\hrule
\phantom{\vbox{%
      \lipsum[4]
      \begin{align*}
        x + y = 3
      \end{align*}%
    }}}
\hrule
\clearpage
\textbf{Here I want the text and equation:}
\lipsum[4] 
\begin{align*}
x + y = 3
\end{align*}

\textbf{Here I want blank space the same size as the equation:}
\hrule
\lipsum[4]
\begin{align*}
  x + y = 3
\end{align*}%
\hrule


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AndrewSmith: You're welcome. Happy TeXing

Answer (score 3):

If I have understood your context, I would suggest the following solution. In my opinion, using the [`exam`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam?lang=en) class is better suited here. This gives you more control.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\printanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question \textbf{Here I want the text and equation:}

  \begin{solution}
    \lipsum[4]
    \begin{align*}
      x + y = 3
    \end{align*}
  \end{solution}

  \question \textbf{Here I want blank space the same size as the
    equation:}


  \begin{solution}
    \lipsum[4]
    \begin{align*}
      x + y = 3
    \end{align*}
  \end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment in/out `\printanswers` to turn on/off leaving the space (solution). Please see the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf) (pp 54-77) to control 
appearance of the space.

Comment: Thanks. I am using a version of this. But the problem (as I stated above) is that I want space instead of the solutions. You said to toggle '\printanswers' - well, if it is off, then no space is left. Essentially, you have answered another query, and left my query to "pg 54-77" of a manual. Thanks though.

Comment: @AndrewSmith Does using `solution` with a specified height inside `[]` (with `\unframedsolutions` in header) help? My point is `exam` class gives you a structured control which is simply unattainable from simple `\phantom` or `\vphantom`, though I am big fan of the later two.

Comment: @AndrewSmith If you decide to use the `exam` class, you may consider using `\questionshook` rather than explicitly making bold each *quesrtion*.

Comment: The bold has no meaning; it is not a question. It is meant to stand out from my example, because it is not part of the example. And no, [] next to solutions doesn't help because I don't know the height of the box I'd want. The height of the box should depend on whatever the solution is. For the record, this is for slides; a presenter version and a student version (which leaves spaces for them to write).

Comment: @AndrewSmith Are you using `beamer` for your presentations?